# NestJS call async service on init

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, nestjs

in my nestjs app I have a service which use a factory service to initialize some kind of adapter.
Since all the methods in my service need to use the adapter initialized by the factory service, I was wondering if there is a way to call the factory service just once. I cannot do it in the constructor because it is an asynchronous call.

What's the best way to achieve it?

This is my service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor(
        private readonly factoryService: FactoryService
    ) {}
```

and this is the call that I need to do:

```
await this.factoryService.createAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Do you just need to call this service on application start?

Comment: actually it would be better (if possible) to call it only when one the method of my service is called.

Comment: But do you only need to call it once, or every time that service gets used?

Comment: Only once.. I am looking for something like lazy loading in Angular.

Comment: [Nest has lazy loading in v8](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lazy-loading-modules)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like if you initialize this service (or a sub service) asynchronously, you'll be able to handle your factory.
I was facing a similar situation when I found in the Nest JS documentation asynchronous providers.

https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/async-providers

It felt like an inelegant solution (and too much work to divide the initialization into another sub service...) so at least for the time I used a variable to check the state but at some point later, I'll use the documented approach.

[image: Example of a simple workaround]

If you choose to use the documentation based example, I found their TypeORM recipe as a nice example of how to set it up properly.

https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/sql-typeorm

Hope this helps. Please comment any feedback!